# Convert JSON date into UNIX timestamp - iOS

Tags: ios, json, unix, timestamp, nsdate

I have an iOS application which downloads a JSON feed from services including Twitter and Instagram. Now some services provide a timestamp with each post in the JSON feed like so:

```
"created_time": "1296748524"
```

However some API's return the date of that post like this:

```
publishedAt = "2014-03-13T13:00:05.000Z"
```

My app needs a timestamp in order to function. So is there a way to convert 'publishedAt' to a UNIX timestamp in iOS?

Thanks for your time :)

Comment: @MartinR You know if you put that as an answer down below, I would be happy to tick it :)

Comment: That's nice of you, but there is no need to duplicate the answer.

Comment: @MartinR fair enough :)